# jquery send variable post

Tags: php, jquery, post

I have this form

```
<form id="formProductos" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/actualizacion/adicionar" method="post">

     <label for="">Ingrese Porcentaje</label>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Escriba el % de actualización" id="actualPorcentaje" name="actualPorcentaje" class="span12" />
</form>


<?php echo '<a id="enviar" href="'.base_url().'index.php/actualizacion/adicionar/'.$marcaid.'"> Actualizar Precios</a>'; ?>
```

and then this function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

$("#enviar").click(function(event){

```
    event.preventDefault();

    var actualPorcentaje = $('#actualPorcentaje').val();

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#formProductos').serialize(),
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/actualizacion/adicionar",
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(data)
                       {
                        if(data.result == true){

                            $('.results').html(data);
                        }
                        else{
                            alert('Ocurrió un error al agregar un producto.');
                        }
                      }
    });
```

});

});

redirected page have this function

function gerenciar(){

```
   ...

    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/actualizacion/gerenciar/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->actualizacion_model->count('actualprecios');

   ...

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);     


    $this->data['results'] = $this->actualizacion_model->get('actualprecios','idActualizacion, actualPorcentaje, actualFecha','',$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));


    $this->data['view'] = 'actualizacionp/actualizacion';

}
```

and "actualizacion_model.php have this function

```
function get($table,$fields,$where='',$perpage=0,$start=0,$one=false,$array='array'){

    $this->db->select($fields.',marcas.marcaNombre');
    $this->db->from($table);
    $this->db->join('marcas','marcas.idMarca = actualprecios.marcaid');
    $this->db->limit($perpage,$start);
    $this->db->order_by('idActualizacion','desc');
    if($where){
        $this->db->where($where);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get();

    $result =  !$one  ? $query->result() : $query->row();
    return $result;
}
```

But it's not working, "porcentaje" is 0

Hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: You mean `actualPorcentaje` is `0`? Where do you set it?

Comment: You're missing code, several closings etc. What is `actualPorcentaje` and where is it coming from? The anchor is not prevented from redirecting etc.

Comment: yes, actualPorcentaje is 0

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value of `actualPorcentaje`.  Try this at the top of your click function:

```
var actualPorcentaje = $('#actualPorcentaje').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to compile form data to send is using [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) on the form. Then you don't need to figure out the individual fields yourself

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#formProductos').serialize(),
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/actualizacion/adicionar",
    dataType: 'json',
    //....
```

Comment: what's happening? page redirect? You don't seem to prevent the click default action

Comment: probably because form isn't submitting , the link is going there. Prevent the default in the click handler

Comment: add `evento.preventDefault()` to the click handler. After that you will need to do some basic debugging if results aren't correct

Comment: I updated the code, ]} was missing, is working but the page is not redirected